# How can I set up network manager to auto-connect at boot-time to a Wi-Fi and a WireGuard VPN?

Tags: network-manager, vpn, autostart, wireguard

How can I set up network manager to auto-connect at boot-time to a Wi-Fi and a WireGuard VPN?

I configured Network Manager with 2 connections: a Wi-Fi and a WireGuard VPN. They both work when I start them up manually. I've set-up both connections to auto-start upon boot. After booting, both connections show as active and connected, but I cannot access the network/internet. If I restart manually the WireGuard VPN, everything works and I am able to access the network again.

This is very annoying! Any ideas what could be wrong and how can I set this up correctly?

[Network connections - Wireguard VPN settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iS5nD.png)
[Network connections - Wi-Fi H369.... settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A30o3.png)

FYI I am running Kubuntu 22.10.
Also FYI, the Network Manager connection configuration files

```
**SS-NL-WG**  
[connection]  
id=SS-NL-WG  
uuid=9xxxxxxxxxx7  
type=wireguard  
autoconnect-priority=10  
interface-name=SS-NL-WG  

[wireguard]  
private-key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx=  

[wireguard-peer.xxxxxxx=]  
endpoint=xxxxxxxx.com:51820  
allowed-ips=0.0.0.0/0;  

[ipv4]  
address1=10.14.0.0/16  
dns=xxxxxxxxxx;  
method=manual  

[ipv6]  
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy  
method=disabled  

##H369A3D4517## (wi-fi)  
[connection]  
id=H369A3D4517  
uuid=fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx9  
type=wifi  
autoconnect-priority=10  

[wifi]  
mode=infrastructure  
ssid=H369A3D4517  

[wifi-security]  
key-mgmt=wpa-psk  
psk=xxxxxxxxxxxx  

[ipv4]  
method=auto  

[ipv6]  
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy  
method=auto
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to achieve the same as you but have not managed yet. My guess why your approach does not work is that probably wireguard comes up first but cannot resolve the IP address of the wireguard endpoint (as the wifi connection is not yet up and so DNS requests wont get through). This means that all your traffic will be routed nowwhere.

Someone posted [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/unable-connect-to-a-wireless-network-when-configured-to-automatically-connect-using-wireguard-configuration/116617/3) that this worked for them:

```
$ nmcli connection modify myvpn-wg connection.autoconnect yes
$ nmcli connection modify WLANEG connection.autoconnect-priority 1
```

Unfortunately, this did not work for me though.

Comment: This is exactly why it doesn't work. Unfortunately this is related to the way network manager works (or better, doesn't) with non-OpenVPN connections. It simply doesn't support  that. I found out this is know for over 10 years but it hasn't been fixed. I checked the upstream/source developers and it's a known issue. What I did eventually is using OpenVPN instead of wireguard VPN protocol and it just works. I am not happy bit I don't want to configure the wireguard package to create a custom peer thay doesn't integrate into the network-manager gui.

Answer (score 0):

I run a non-Ubuntu Linux. Where I usually work I have three SSIDs I can connect to. This code runs in /etc/rc.d/rc.local. It connects Network Manager to the WIFI connection with the strongest signal at boot time. The "magic", I think, is nothing more than the 5s pause that gives NM time to sort itself. If all the plain-text info make you nervous or the delay is annoying, I'd say stick to manual connections. I would...if they did. ;-)

NOTE: "prompt> nmcli device wifi" lists all detectable access points w/info

```
sleep 5
SSID=`nmcli device wifi | grep -w '[VarLenSSIDName_1]\|-w [VarLenSSIDName_2]\|-w [VarLenSSIDName_3]'`

if [[ $(grep '[VarLenSSIDName_1]' <<<${SSID}) ]]; then
    echo "Activating wlan[#]: Connecting to [VarLenSSIDName1]..."
    nmcli device wifi connect [VarLenSSIDName_1] password [PlainTestPW_1]
fi

if [[ $(grep '[VarLenSSIDName_2]' <<<${SSID}) ]]; then
    echo "Activating wlan[#]: Connecting to [VarLenSSIDName_2]..."
    nmcli device wifi connect [VarLenSSIDName_2] password [PlainTestPW_2]
fi

if [[ $(grep '[VarLenSSIDName_3]' <<<${SSID}) ]]; then
    echo "Activating wlan[#]: Connecting to [VarLenSSIDName_3]..."
    nmcli device wifi connect [VarLenSSIDName_3] password [PlainTestPW_3]
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you. I was able to fix it by going into nmtui > edit a connection > *my wireguard connection* and turning on the "Never use this network for default route"
Everything seems to work fine. Hope this helps